# How to close a specific program due to inactivity in python

Tags: python, operating-system, system

So I have programs that need to run continuously on my pc, but my kid likes to play fortnite on it and leave the game on after he's done. So I'm trying to figure out how to automatically close that task specifically after 30 min of inactivity but leave the pc on. Is there a library that can listen for input through a USB? Or keystrokes? Or is there an easier way to continuously scan for user input at the system level?

Maybe

```
import os
```

but im lost there

Comment: Do you want to quit the game after 30 minutes of inactivity?

Comment: I hadn't set a specific time, but yeah probably 30 minutes. Maybe 15 minutes. Just as long as only that game closes.

Comment: If you're using Windows, consider defining an [idle trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-idle-conditions) via the Task Scheduler. Writing code is fun and often necessary, but in cases like this you're probably better off using maintained implementations provided by your OS.